# LIMIT in php sql not working

Tags: php, sql, limit

Hello everyone i would like to ask you why, when i put limit 0,5 and 5,10 it does not work correctly here is my code.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vn_questions WHERE published = 1 limit 0,5 ");
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo $data['author'];
}
```

it gives me 5 results but when i put

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vn_questions WHERE published = 1 limit 5,10 ");
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo $data['author'];
}
```

it gives me 6 .. where is the problem and how Can i fix it? I tried +1 -1 but the output is not working correctly.

Comment: `5-6-7-8-9-10 = "6"` instances. `0` is none, then you start counting up to 5 = 5 --- What is your expected result?

Comment: If you don't want to set a limit, then leave `LIMIT` out, or drop the first number. I.e.: `LIMIT 10` and that will give you 10 results. Oh, and my comment comment, that was "in a nutshell" ;-)

Comment: i think there may be some confusion, because i believe (correct me if I'm wrong) but MSSQL and MYSQL handle limits differently. for mysql the numbers are not a lower and upper bounds. see my answer below for how limit works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the syntax for MYSQL `LIMIT` is  `LIMIT OFFSET COUNT`, so what your second query is saying is start at record 5, and show me 10 results. does your table only have 6 records in it? since that's less than 10 it will only show those 6 available.

From the SQL manual

`With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):`

AND

`With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set:`

Comment: if you could click the checkbox next to the answer to accept it, that would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks a lot man I should check the google first but you realy helped me a lot ;)